# Getting {ValueError} 'a' must be 1-dimensoinal for list of lists from np.random.choice

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a toy training set from the XOR function:

```
xor = [[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0]]

input_x = np.random.choice(a=xor, size=200)
```

However, this is giving me

```
{ValueError} 'a' must be 1-dimensoinal
```

But, if I add e.g. a number to this list:

```
xor = [[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0],
       1337]       # With this it will work

input_x = np.random.choice(a=xor, size=200)
```

it starts to work. Why is this the case and how can I make this work without having to add another primitive to the `xor` list?

Comment: what do you expect from `np.random.choice(a=xor, size=200)` a single number or an array with 3 values?

Comment: @BloodyD I expected a list of 200 randomly drawn samples from `xor` with replacement.

Comment: Why not just use `random.choice` instead? Since you are working with Python's lists already.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In case of an array I would  do the following:

```
xor = np.array([[0,0,0],
       [0,1,1],
       [1,0,1],
       [1,1,0]])
rnd_indices = np.random.choice(len(xor), size=200)

xor_data = xor[rnd_indices]
```

Comment: Well, I guess I'll have to go that road :D Thanks :)

Comment: you could also optimize the code, as others suggested with `np.random.choice(len(xor), size=200)` ;)

Comment: This will take a single element in a multidimensional array, right? If you have 100 images, your array may have a shape like (100 x 32 x 32 x 3), and this line of code will return a single image, with shape (32 x 32 x 3). What we are searching is a random subset of the array, with shape ( A x 32 x 32 x 3) where A is the number of randomly picked values

Comment: @FedericoDorato no it won't. By settings `size=200` in the `np.random.choice` function, rnd_indices returns an array of 200 values, then indexing with this array returns your desired `A=200 x 32 x 32 x 3` array. (I hope, it is not too late to clarify this :) )

Answer (score 6):

If you want a random list from `xor`, you should probably be doing this.

```
xor[np.random.choice(len(xor),1)]
```

Comment: This will take a single element in a multidimensional array, right? If you have 100 images, your array may have a shape like (100 x 32 x 32 x 3), and this line of code will return a single image, with shape (32 x 32 x 3). What we are searching is a random subset of the array, with shape ( A x 32 x 32 x 3) where A is the number of randomly picked values

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `random` package instead:

```
import random
input_x = [random.choice(xor) for _ in range(200)]
```

Comment: I don't think you want to transpose `xor`.

Comment: I assumed the samples were to be of 4 elements. But I'll update the answer, thanks!

Comment: Assuming that the OP was searching how to take multiple random elements (I believe that is the case) this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting!! Seems that numpy implicitly converts the input to `np.array` first. so, for your first input

```
np.array(xor).shape == (4, 3)
```

while for the second value

```
np.array(xor).shape == (5, )
```

so, the second value is seen by numpy as 1d!!!

So, to pick a random row, just pick a random index, and then the corresponding row

```
ind = np.choice(len(xor))
random_row = xor[ind, :]
```

Comment: yes, numpy tries to identify the common datatype of your values in the array. In the first case this is `int` but in the second it is only `object`, since it compares objects in the same dimension. Hence, you get an array with dtype `object` and the shape `(5,)` for the 2nd value

Comment: thanks, good explanation. do you remember where in the documentation (or any other source) is this mentioned? numpy documentation is a little sparse...

Comment: I don't know, where the documentation for this is, but I have faced it couple of times on my own. *EDIT* short googling: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html#numpy.array "[...] dtype : data-type, optional
The desired data-type for the array. **If not given**, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. [...]"

Comment: Again, as other answers, this will just return a single random value, not many

Answer (score 0):

With focus on performance, we could use the decimal number equivalents of those four numbers, feed those to [`np.random.choice()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) to generate `200` such numbers randomly chosen and finally get their binary equivalents with bit-shift operation.

Thus, an implementation would be -

```
def bitshift_approach(N):
    nums = np.random.choice(np.array([0,3,5,6]),size=(N))
    return ((nums & (1 << np.arange(3))[:,None])!=0).T.astype(int)
```

Another approach would be using very similar to what others have suggested to use `np.random.choice(len(xor)` to generate the row indices and then use `row-indexing` to select `rows` off `xor`. A slight modification to that would be to use [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to select those rows. With such repeated indices, as is the case here, this should be performant.

Thus, an alternative approach would be -

```
np.take(xor,np.random.choice(len(xor), size=N))
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [42]: N = 200

In [43]: %timeit xor[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(xor)), size=N)]
    ...: %timeit xor[np.random.choice(len(xor), size=N)]
    ...: %timeit bitshift_approach(N)
    ...: %timeit np.take(xor,np.random.choice(len(xor), size=N))
    ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.3 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.3 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 59.4 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 35 µs per loop

In [44]: N = 1000

In [45]: %timeit xor[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(xor)), size=N)]
    ...: %timeit xor[np.random.choice(len(xor), size=N)]
    ...: %timeit bitshift_approach(N)
    ...: %timeit np.take(xor,np.random.choice(len(xor), size=N))
    ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 69.5 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 64.7 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.7 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.7 µs per loop

In [46]: N = 10000

In [47]: %timeit xor[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(xor)), size=N)]
    ...: %timeit xor[np.random.choice(len(xor), size=N)]
    ...: %timeit bitshift_approach(N)
    ...: %timeit np.take(xor,np.random.choice(len(xor), size=N))
    ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 363 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 351 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 225 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 134 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **random.choice()** directly  and just run it 200 times to get 200 sample
Since np.random.choice() requires values to be in 1 d shape  like ["1","2","3"]
and can't work with a list of lists or list of tuples only **list of scaler values**